# C#: Round decimal for display only when the decimal point is 0 (eg: 3.00 --> 3)

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting

I am storing Amount in Decimal(18,2). But most of my data is actually integer with only few decimal. So when I display the amount for each item in the table, the number display is all 3.00, 4.00, 5.00 and so on.

I feel it is kind of weird to display all the 0 as the decimal point. I wish to format the number when display if the decimal point is 0.

Currently I am displaying the amount like this:

```
  <td id="amnt@(item.FoodID)" class="amountfield">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodAmount)
  </td>
```

Any idea?? Appreciate every help... thanks...

Comment: How should `4.50m` be show? `4.50` or `4.5`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at your code I assume that you are using ASP.Net MVC for your application. You can use DataAnnotation for formatting your data.

You can try using DisplayFormat in your model property.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")] 
Decimal FoodAmount{ get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point here. It should show decimal places when there are decimal values, but if the decimal equates to a whole number then decimal places should not be shown. I don't think display format will do the job here

Comment: Good Idea. But he doesn't want the `"N"` format but rather a custom `"0.##"`.

Comment: @musefan: well, display format _will_ do the job, you just need to specify the right one. I don't know if it accepts custom format strings, though.

Comment: @noah1989: Yeah it does not seem to accept custom string formats, so it _wont_ work

Comment: +1 for using the `DisplayFormat` attribute. Using `ToSting()` directly would cause code duplication if the value is displayed at different places.

Comment: @Maheep: It should be `"{0:0.##}"`. Because it is passed to `String.Format`, not `Double.ToString`

Comment: Thanks, I am using  @String.Format("{0:0.##}", item.FoodAmount)

Answer (score 4):

Use `ToString(string)` with a custom format using the ["#" custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD)

```
item.FoodAmount.ToString("0.##")
```

This shows up to two digits but omits them if they are non-significant zeroes.

Comment: Hi, can I do this in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript has very limited number formatting features. There are some custom functions floating around though. Just google for "javascript number to string".

Comment: I need to do it at both way, so i use  @String.Format("{0:0.##}", item.FoodAmount) and ((Math.round((value * Math.pow(10, 2)).toFixed(2 - 1)) / Math.pow(10, 2)).toFixed(2)) * 1;

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this will help...

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodAmount % 1 == 0 ? item.FoodAmount.ToString("F0") : item.FoodAmount.ToString("F2"))
```

This should provide results like the following:

```
FoodAmount | Output
--------------------
 3.00      |  3
 3.01      |  3.01
 3.5       |  3.50
```

I have purposefully suqeezed this into one line to suit your Html Helper code, but you could create a helper function/extension method for this if you prefer.

The basic idea is to get the remainder of a divide by 1. If the result is zero (i.e. it can be divided by 1 with no remainder) then it can be assumed to be a whole number

**Alternative**: This would also be an option, and might make for better reading...

```
item.FoodAmount.ToString("F2").TrimEnd('0', '.')
```

This might even give you better results...

```
FoodAmount | Output
--------------------
 3.00      |  3
 3.01      |  3.01
 3.5       |  3.5
```

Comment: Alternative is buggy. It trims leading `0`s and `.`s. have fun with `0.10` And its treatment of culture is inconsistent. It uses current culture for formatting, but assumes `.` as decimal separator when trimming.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You're right. You could solve this by using `InvariantCulture` and `TrimEnd`, though. But actually this is a job for (custom) format strings.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Sorry, it was meant to be `TrimEnd` and a `.` separator was in the OP spec - fair comment to make though ;)

Comment: It will return 1 if decimal value is 10.00M; :(

Answer (score 0):

DataFormatString works well in ViewModel

That would also add a thousand separator, if needed

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,##0.##}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked the best for me

```
[Test]
public void DecimalFormatTests()
{
    var amt1 = 1000000m;
    var amt2 = 1000000.10m;

    var format = "0.#";

    Console.WriteLine(amt1.ToString("\\£0,0.#"));
    Console.WriteLine(amt2.ToString("\\£0,0.#"));

}
```

Output :

> £10,00,000 
>   £10,00,000.1